# Docker on Linux - Empty mounted volumes

Tags: linux, docker, elementary-os

I'm trying to get my docker setup to work on my linux machine (it works fine on OSX). I can't for the life of me get the volumes to mount properly on the linux box.

I'm on Elementary OS 0.4 Loki (64-bit)

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:14:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.04.0-ce
 API version:  1.28 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   4845c56
 Built:        Wed Apr  5 18:45:47 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

docker-machine version

```
docker-machine version 0.10.0, build 76ed2a6
```

I'm doing the following;

```
docker run -it -a stdout -a stderr -v /home/joel/Sites:/var/www/test --name=app pallantdigital/php7
```

However when I look in the container, at the /var/www folder, while it seems to pull in the folder structure ( or at least some of it ), and there are no files in the folders.

I've also tried using docker-compose like so;

```
image: pallantdigital/php7
  volumes:
    - /home/joel/Sites:/var/www/test
```

With the same result, the folder clearly gets 'mounted' but there are no files.

If I do docker inspect on the normal docker run container I get the following under 'Mounts'

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/joel/Sites",
            "Destination": "/var/www/test",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
```

It's strange that 'mode' is empty.

The purpose of this was to build a development environment with a live/editable code base on the local machine which is synced across to the docker container (this is how I have it running on my mac). The php7 image is just Ubuntu with PHP7 installed.

Unfortunately most of the support questions around seem to be for Windows and Mac OSX. I've tried a few of the things people suggest, i.e. sending UID, Making sure that VirtualBox Shared Folder included the /home directory.

Any assistance would be grand, let me know if I can offer any extra information.

Comment: Hi Joel, have you checked if Docker can access the volume host path? Remember that the full path must be executable for the user running the daemon.

Besides, if you run the command

docker volume ls

what do you get?

Ciao
Maurizio

Comment: Hi @MaurizioBenedetti Thanks for your reply. Do you have a suggestion for the 'correct' way to make the folder accessible to docker? (It's all chmod to 777 atm). docker volume ls actually doesn't return anything when just using docker run. I updated my post with the docker inspect 'mounts' though if you look above^

Comment: Hi Joel,
if the container starts (and it should, even if the volume is not there) you can "open a bash session" using the command "docker exec -it [container-id] bash". From there you can get a clue on why the OS cannot write on the folder and check if the folder is actually there. This is an option. To simplify the permission problem, you should make sure that all the folders are executable by the user running docker. To make your life easier, create a folder in the root file system and make sure docker is the owner. Another question, do you have selinux running?

Comment: Yeah I'm 'bashing' in once it's built which is how I can see that some of the folders are there but no files. It seems to go X number of folders deep until it finds a file, and then just stops. When you say 'running docker' in which context do you mean? For instance, my username is 'joel', this is the owner and group of the files, and I am logged into 'joel' when I run 'docker run'.

Comment: I'm wondering if I need some sort of 'docker run --user=whatever' combination or something. No to Selinux unless it's bundled with Elementary OS. I tried with chowning to www-data and then doing --user=www-data:www-data however the /var/www/Sites... directories within the container are all chownd as root O.o

Comment: Mounting on Mac is different, more permissive. On Mac it will lie to the container, whatever user runs in the container, osxfs pretends that user owns the mounted volume. That is not true on Linux, you have to ensure the uid running in the container is capable of reading the mounted directory. I wrote more about this problem in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43213455/2449905).

Comment: Thanks Dan I will check it out. Interesting you say this as on my Mac I did originally have problems with ownership and had to create a new user on the image with the same uid as my mac user to get it working. I'm expecting it's the same problem.

Comment: @DanLowe I've rebuilt my dockerfile using `User ubuntu` which maps to 1000:1000 (same as my linux box user joel who owns the directory I'm mapping). I also included --user=1000:1000 in the docker run command. My entrypoint ends in bash so I get logged straight into the container, it's now logging me into the container as ubuntu user. However the folder it creates (I tried /home/ubuntu/test) is still owned by root. Any thoughts?

Comment: I see you talking about docker-machine and Virtualbox. Why are you using those if your server is already running Linux?

Comment: Hi @DanLowe, my new desktop is Linux, this is for a local dev environment. To be fair I'm quite new to Docker (and desktop linux) and there's a bucket ton to read, I kind of just hoped it would port nicely from my Mac to Linux. I was not aware of another driver other than virtualbox, should I be using something else??

Comment: If you are running Linux you can run Docker directly, no VM needed. If you are doing it for isolation, fine, but then the uid that matters is probably the one in the docker-machine, not the one on the main Linux system. Or maybe you should sync all 3 of them... I have no experience with using docker-machine like that, though.

Comment: @DanLowe - From the documentation (or severe lack-of in relation to linux) I wasn't aware that there was another option other than using docker-machine? I tried this, but had the exact same result. The mapped directory (/var/www/test) is owned by root, I even tried chowning /var/www in the dockerfile. It's like the docker command is STILL being run as root even though I'm not running it as root, and i'm passing --user=1000:1000 :/

Comment: Are you sure the volume is actually an external mount? If you `df -h` in the container exec, is `/var/www/test` a mounted filesystem inside the container? That there are no files is odd, unless there were no files in the Sites directory you are mounting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141513/discussion-between-joel-and-dan-lowe).