# Wanted persistent data with Docker volumes but have empty directories instead

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm writing a Dockerfile for a java application but I'm struggling with volumes: the mounted volumes are empty.
I've read the Dockerfile reference guide and the best pratice to write Dockerfiles, but, for a start, my example is quite complicated.

What I want to do is to be able to have the following items on the host (in a mounted volume):

1. **configuration** folder,
2. **log** folder,
3. **data** folder,
4. **properties** files

Let me summarize :
When the application is **installed** (extracted from the tar.gz with the RUN command), it writes a bunch of files and directories (including log and conf).
When the application is **started** (with CMD or ENTRYPOINT), it creates a data folder if it doesn't exist and put data files in it.

I'm only interested in:

1. /rootapplicationfolder/conf_folder
2. /rootapplicationfolder/log_folder
3. /rootapplicationfolder/data_folder
4. /rootapplicationfolder/properties_files

I'm not interested in /rootapplicationfolder/binary_files

There is something taht I dont't see. I've read and applied the information found in the two following links without success.

Questions:
Should I 'mkdir'only the top level dir on the host to be mapped with /rootapplicationfolder ?What about the files ?

Is the order of 'VOLUME' in my Dockerfile important ? 
Does it need to be placed before or after the deflating (RUN tar zxvf compressed_application) ?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/T84nlzw_vpI

[Docker on Linux - Empty mounted volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346605/docker-on-linux-empty-mounted-volumes)

Answer (score 2):

Try using Docker-compose, use the `volumes` property to set what path you want to mount between your machine and your container.

version 2 Example

```
web:
image: my-web-app
build:.
command: bash -c "npm start"
ports:
  - "8888:8888"
volumes:
  - .:/home/app/code         (This mount your current path with /home/app/code)
  - /home/app/code/node_modules/          (unmount sub directory)
environment:
  NODE_ENV: development
```

You can look at this repository too.
https://github.com/williamcabrera4/docker-flask/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've managed to get want I want.
First, I haven't ant ***VOLUME*** directive in my ***Dockerfile***.
All the shared directories are created with the *-v* option of the *docker run* command.

After that, I had issues with extracting the archive whenever the "extracting" would overwrite an existing directory mounted with *-v* because it's simply not possible.

So, I deflate the archive somewhere where the ***-v*** mounted volumes don't exist and AFTER this step, I ***mv*** the contents of deflated/somedirectory to *-vMountedSomeDirectory*.

I still had issues with docker on CentOS, the ***mv*** would copy the files to the destination but would be unable to delete them at the source after the move. I got tired and simply use a debian distribution instead.