# Docker volume: File owner set to root when created from host machine

Tags: docker, macos, dockerfile, docker-for-mac

I have a directory in my Docker contains which is mounted to a dir on the host OS. Sometimes, when I create a file in that directory from within host OS as a non-root, in the container, it shows owner is "root". How can I make sure all files I create will be non-root? Or at least allow read/write for non-root user inside the dir?

My Dockerfile: `VOLUME /home/mahdix/command`
My command line: `docker run -v "$(pwd)"/command:/home/mahdix/command ...`

on the host OS, as a normal user:
goto /command -> `vim test` -> make some changes -> save and exit

inside the container, when I list files in the "/home/mahdix/command" directory, they belong to root:root.

I'm running these inside Mac OS. The base image is Ubuntu:22.04.

Comment: I think [Docker on MacOSX does not translate file ownership correctly in volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097341/docker-on-macosx-does-not-translate-file-ownership-correctly-in-volumes) describes this same issue.

Comment: Can you run the container as non-root user ?

Comment: @Philippe I have `USER mahdix` in my Dockerfile and all processes are run under this user. I think as David mentioned it is a Mac OS issue.

Comment: I built an image on MacOS and ran without problem. Can you post a minimal reproducible example ?